# High quality images leaving the app slow

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I use Xamarin.Forms where only in Android, the high quality image leaves the application slow. (iOS and Windows Universal work normally) How can I resolve this at my command?

```
<Image Scale="1.0" Aspect="AspectFill" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="300">
    <Image.Source>
        <UriImageSource Uri="{Binding url}" CacheValidity="5" CachingEnabled="True"/>
    </Image.Source>
    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnTapped" />
    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
</Image>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [FFImageLoading](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.FFImageLoading/) library. It loads images asynchronously and have many useful features. 
Also you can consider creating different images for different screens so that with low resolution screen would be used fast low resolution images. Learn more [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/resources_in_android/part_4_-_creating_resources_for_varying_screens/).